# Опасность использования не Java в Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Я пишу для Android около 1.5 лет, все это время я учусь в университете и проекты для фриланса пишу на языке kotlin. Проекты работают хорошо и язык мне очень нравится. Стоит так же отметить что использование этого языка не исключает наличия кода на java в проекте. Но скоро выпуск и меня не покидает ощущение, что решающим с точки зрения работодателя будет именно опыт использования java.

Как вы считаете стоит отказаться от использования kotlin и вернуться на java или же я напрасно беспокоюсь? Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ 29 мая 2017: Котлин признан ещё одним языком разработки на Android, популярность его заметно выросла.

В силу того, что и Kotlin, и Java собираются на одну общую платформу, бинарная и прочая совместимость не помеха, а важен язык как язык проекта.

По-моему, с точки зрения работодателя важно, сможете ли Вы работать в команде, и тогда знание Java вам поможет куда больше, чем знание Kotlin: при всех его плюсах, он гораздо менее популярен, и, соответственно, гораздо меньше вероятность, что Вы найдёте себе место, где будут использовать Kotlin. Это критично только в том случае, если над вашей частью проекта работать будет только вы и никто после или до вас, но это редко.

Ну а если вы точно знаете, что работать будете только там, где будут использовать Kotlin, то конечно вопрос стоять не будет.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я сам склонялся к подобным выводам, да и неопределенность в плане рабочего места не дает дать однозначный ответ.

Comment: @nekaneka тем более что Kotlin, как я знаю, разделяет б*о*льшую часть идеологии Java, изучить и то, и то будет не так сложно. Удачи!

Answer (score 4):

Не важно на каком ты пишете языке, если есть опыт разработки, то его можно применить в любом проекте на любом языке. Знаю человека которого позвали на вакансию Java разработчика без знания Java, но он к тому моменту уже был хорошим С# разработчиком.